# Bootstrap Tab Collapse plugin - How to hide collapsed tabs in mobile when there is no content?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap Tab Collapse plugin](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse) in my CMS and I would like to hide the tabs when there's no content provided in the tabs (via my CMS). I can easily hide() the tabs in desktop viewport, but I can't seem to find a way to do the same on mobile viewport when the tabs are collapsed.

This is the code I am using to hide the tabs by checking if a specific element has HTML or not:

```
if ($.trim($('.the-element-to-check').html()).length == 0) {
  $('#event-tabbed-accordion').hide();
}
```

This does not work, it's like #event-tabbed-accordion does not exist in the DOM or cannot be accessed for some reason. I can access #event-tabbed (its previous sibling) but not the #event-tabbed-accordion that I want to hide.

So, I tried targeting #event-tabbed and then testing something with its next() sibling (I tried adding a test-class to next() element which is the element I want to hide, but that didn't work either, next() skips the element I want to hide and it's adding the test class to the element after #event-tabbed-accordion.

```
if ($.trim($('.the-element-to-check').html()).length == 0) {
  $('#event-tabbed').next().addClass('test-class');
}
```

And this is what happens after adding the test-class, screenshot below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why I cannot access #event-tabbed-accordion?

Comment: It has a `visible-xs` `class` so make sure you test your code for `xs` width.

Comment: Yea, and visible-xs gets @media(max-width:767px).visible-xs{display:block!important;} from bootstrap.min.css but I should be able to find this element in the DOM and override it's settings, right?

Comment: Try to use `$(#event-tabbed-accordion').css('display', 'none !important');`. It will overwrite style provided by `xs-visible` class.

Comment: I tried that but `#event-tabbed-accordion` is not accessible in the DOM. I can see it when I am inspecting the code but I cannot access it. Is it because that element is dynamically added by Tab Collapse?

Comment: Maybe try do put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ your code });` ?

Comment: It is in document ready, I even tried changing the loading order of the .js references but that didn't help either.

Comment: Here's a pen [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNKjQK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNKjQK) the second set of tabs with empty tab content should be removed when the tabs are collapsed, but it doesn't work. It works on widescreen but not on mobile when the tabs are collapsed.

Comment: http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/aNgyQx

Comment: Thank you @makshh.. I am giving this a try.